# Big square with another smaller square attached in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a square whit another square attached but smaller. The idea it put text in the big square and an icon in the smaller square (I put an image of example at the end).

I'm using bootstrap 4, so the idea it's build this using html and css not only puting a image, to have the responsive features of BS4 and a consitence in the whole webpage.

Thank you in advance for any help!

[Big square whit a small square attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M23hq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit over simplified, but you could have something like this:

HTML:

```
   <div class="parent-box">
      <div class="big-box">
        <p>Nuestro Servicio</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>

      <div class="small-box">
        <i>icon</i>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Then css:

```
.parent-box {
  display: flex;
}

.big-box {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}

.small-box {
    background-color: green;
    height: 24px; //height of the icon
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a good start, i'm going to try something in that way.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Flex can help you do basically anything, you can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with ::before and ::after pseudoclasses?

You could do something like this. This assumes all preexisting styles on your big-box and you'll also need to add background color and sizing to the ::after element to make it look exactly the way you want it, but in terms of positioning this is how it can work. There are some great additional resources below from a great guy name Kevin Powell on the powerful and impressive capability of ::before and ::after.

```
.big-box {
  position: relative;
}

.big-box::after {
  content: url(<icon-image>);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 15%;
}
```

Before & After Pseudo-elements 1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGiirUiWslI

Before & After Pseudo-elements 2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoRbkm8XgfQ

Before & After Pseudo-elements 3
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djbtPnNmc0I